# Extracting unique rows in a 3+ column matrix

Tags: r, unique, rows

Using R, I am trying to extract unique rows in a matrix, where a "unique row" is subject to all the values in a given row.

For example if I had this data set:

```
x = matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,5,1,2,2,1,2,1,5,3,5,2,1,1),6,3)
```

Rows 1 & 6, and rows 4 & 5 are duplicated since (1,1,5) = (5,1,1) and (2,1,2) = (2,2,1).

Ultimately, i'm trying to end up with something in the form of:

```
y = matrix(c(1,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,5,3,5,2),4,3)
```

or

```
z = matrix(c(1,1,2,5,2,2,2,1,3,5,1,1),4,3)
```

The order doesn't matter as long as only one of the unique rows remains. I've searched online, but functions such as unique() and duplicated() have only worked for exact matching rows.

Thanks in advance for any help you provide.

Comment: `x[!duplicated(apply(x, 1, sort), MARGIN = 2), ]`

Answer (score 0):

Another answer: use sets.  Slightly modified matrix:

```
library(sets)
x <- matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,5,5, 1,2,2,1,2,1,5, 5,3,5,2,1,1,1),7,3)
x
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    5
[2,]    1    2    3
[3,]    1    2    5
[4,]    2    1    2
[5,]    2    2    1
[6,]    5    1    1
[7,]    5    5    1
```

If (5,1,1) = (5,5,1) you can use just ordinary sets:

```
a <- sapply(1:nrow(x), function(i) as.set(x[i,]))
x[!duplicated(a),]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    5
[2,]    1    2    3
[3,]    1    2    5
[4,]    2    1    2
```

Note: rows 6 and 7 are both gone.

If (5,1,1) != (5,5,1), use generalized sets:

```
b <- sapply(1:nrow(x), function(i) as.gset(x[i,]))
x[!duplicated(b),]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    5
[2,]    1    2    3
[3,]    1    2    5
[4,]    2    1    2
[5,]    5    5    1
```